# How to include assets in react-native build in NX monorepo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm building a react-native app using NX monorepo. I have created a lib (let's say `libs/my-lib) and I have kept my app logo inside` libs/my-lib/src/assets/app_logo.png`. Then I import it inside` apps/my-app/src/screens/WelcomeScreen.tsx`. But, it doesn't show the image.

But if import image from `apps/my-app/src/assets/app_logo.png` it works.

Then I tried to bundle the image in assets and import using the uri. But, how I can include the assets folder?

How I can fix this issue?